# Google Maps API (JavaScript): Maps not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm obviously making a thing which is meant to show a Map.

Literally nothing happens - no Map, no Errors, no crash and burn.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpgrLi55xM68AaSJOQPX5nzEOV7sw4KVY&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
    function initMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.419824, -3.0509294),

            mapTypeId: 'satellite',
            scrollwheel: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }

</script>
```

I've tried changing the width/height of the parent div to PX's with no luck.

Any help is great

Cheers

[image: A bit of imagery help]

For a better insight, view the full page code here:
http://pastebin.com/XrRYgtjz

Comment: Is your script calling `initMap()` somewhere?

Comment: No, but in the new and "improved", bulked and overly big URLs for the Maps API is the callback function (see at end) which is whats meant to trigger it. Just tried manually calling it then and still no luck

Answer (score 2):

I would say you have two issues.

1. your map div doesn't have a size (you don't specify the size of the containing element for the anonymous div `<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">`).
2. your [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) doesn't contain the **required**/manditory `zoom` property.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vup8w4pw/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.419824, -3.0509294),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite',
    scrollwheel: true
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
<script deferred async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Still no! I've literally copied that word for word and despite it working inside  the jsFiddle, it still doesn't on the website

Comment: Check your HTML/CSS - Does the map div have a size? If it is a percentage size, are there percentages defined all the way up to a fixed size or the HTML element?  You are using bootstrap, so this is likely the issue.  If setting a fixed size for the map div makes it display, then this is definitely the issue.  If that doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (the posted code is not complete and your pastebin is not minimal).

Comment: you are the king. Yes that was the problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
```

Maybe problem in `height`. Try change to 400px.
Or

```
<div style="height:400px; width: 100%;">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:100%; width: 100%;></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
<div style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function initMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas");
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.419824, -3.0509294),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            scrollwheel: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }   
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpgrLi55xM68AaSJOQPX5nzEOV7sw4KVY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Just a big empty white space now

Comment: Thats the weirdest thing, there is none. Only time I get an error is calling the function straight away, in which it says google isn't defined. If I try manually calling it after its loaded, the function runs but nothing else works.

Comment: try **mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE** instead mapTypeId: 'satellite'

Comment: @FBMG_, I edited my answer. Also I removed _<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpgrLi55xM68AaSJOQPX5nzEOV7sw4KVY&callback=initMap"></script>_   to the last line.

Comment: I've copied the HTML to pastebin for people to have a better insight - view here: http://pastebin.com/XrRYgtjz

Comment: Did you have this error _RefererNotAllowedMapError_ ?

Comment: Absolutely no error at all showing up which is quite frankly bizzare. The referrer is set to only allow _*.domain.com/*_ and _*.domain.com_ but as they're the right domains then that isn't the issue. I've just checked the Google API Error log and nothing's showing up there either.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe use simple example [map-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you've described the new map in your mapOptions variable. Try changing the syntax to something like this, passing mapCanvas as the first argument and the options as the second argument:

```
  var mapOptions = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, {
            center: {lat: 53.419824, lng: -3.0509294}, 
            mapTypeId: 'satellite',
            scrollwheel: true
    });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I wish it did! Thanks anyway :(